Firebase functions in flutter project: Deploy fail when implementing function to automatically create/delete user in firestore db
`const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.newUserSignup = functions
  .region('eur3')
  .auth.user().onCreate(async (userRecord) => {
    const { uid, email } = userRecord;

    if (!uid) {
     console.error('No user ID');
     return null;
    }

    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).set({
      email: email || null,
      created_at: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    });
  });

exports.userDeleted = functions
  .region('eur3')
  .auth.user().onDelete(async (userRecord) => {
    const { uid } = userRecord;

    if (!uid) {
     console.error('No user ID');
      return null;
    }

    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).delete();
  });`

How can I improve this code to make such functions work? I managed to deploy some exemplary functions, but any version of mentioned code does not work. Most common error is : ,,
Error: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error''
